# Add params to given URL in Python

Tags: python, url

Suppose I was given a URL.
It might already have GET parameters (e.g. `http://example.com/search?q=question`) or it might not (e.g. `http://example.com/`).

And now I need to add some parameters to it like `{'lang':'en','tag':'python'}`. In the first case I'm going to have `http://example.com/search?q=question&lang=en&tag=python` and in the second — `http://example.com/search?lang=en&tag=python`.

Is there any standard way to do this?

Answer (score 234, accepted):

There are a couple of quirks with the `urllib` and `urlparse` modules. Here's a working example:

```
try:
    import urlparse
    from urllib import urlencode
except: # For Python 3
    import urllib.parse as urlparse
    from urllib.parse import urlencode

url = "http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=question"
params = {'lang':'en','tag':'python'}

url_parts = list(urlparse.urlparse(url))
query = dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(url_parts[4]))
query.update(params)

url_parts[4] = urlencode(query)

print(urlparse.urlunparse(url_parts))
```

`ParseResult`, the result of `urlparse()`, [is read-only](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse) and we need to convert it to a `list` before we can attempt to modify its data.

Comment: You probably want to use `urlparse.parse_qs` instead of `parse_qsl`. The latter returns a list whereas you want a dict. See http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs.

Comment: @florian : At least in python 2.7 you then need to call `urlencode` as `urllib.urlencode(query, doseq=True)`. Otherwise, parameters that existed in the original url are not preserved correctly (because they are returned as tuples from @parse_qs@

Comment: I've rewritten this to work in Python 3 as well. [Code here](https://gist.github.com/rokcarl/20b5bf8dd9b1998880b7).

Comment: The results of `urlparse()` and `urlsplit()` are actually `namedtuple` instances. Thus you can assign them directly to a variable and use `url_parts = url_parts._replace(query = …)` to update it.

Comment: Yes, @Feuermurmel's comment is right: it is more readable as a dict than a list. `url_parts.query` vs `url_parts[4]`. As @Feuermurmel mentions, you would then need to use `_replace` as `urlparse` returns a `ParseResult`, not a dict, so you can't do `url_parts.query = ...`.

Comment: Caution - this implementation removes repeated query parameters that some RESTful services use. With a little modification this can be fixed. query = urlparse.parse_qsl(url_parts[4])
query += params.items()
But then if you want to replace exiting query params using dict, takes a little more.

Comment: This implementation will fail with a URL that does not yet have a slash after the domain name, such has "http://hello.com". This can be fixed with `if url_parts[4]: url_parts[2] = url_parts[2] or '/'`.

Comment: @Feuermurmel Expanding on your comment, we can also get rid of `urlunparse(url_parts)` by using `url_parts._replace(query = …).geturl()`.

Answer (score 95):

Outsource it to the battle tested [requests library](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/models.py#L347).

This is how I will do it:

```
from requests.models import PreparedRequest
url = 'http://example.com/search?q=question'
params = {'lang':'en','tag':'python'}
req = PreparedRequest()
req.prepare_url(url, params)
print(req.url)
```

Comment: It doesn't merge query string parameters in case if they should be overriden, so the url can be like `http://example.com/search?q=question&q=someval`.

Comment: there is not a reason to override the value of a given query parameter as multiple values for a parameter are widely supported. [query params wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Web_forms).

Answer (score 72):

### Why

I've been not satisfied with all the solutions on this page (*come on, where is our favorite copy-paste thing?*) so I wrote my own based on answers here. It tries to be complete and more Pythonic. I've added a handler for **dict** and **bool** values in arguments to be more consumer-side (*JS*) friendly, but they are yet optional, you can drop them.

### How it works

**Test 1:** Adding new arguments, handling Arrays and Bool values:

```
url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/test'
new_params = {'answers': False, 'data': ['some','values']}

add_url_params(url, new_params) == \
    'http://stackoverflow.com/test?data=some&data=values&answers=false'
```

**Test 2:** Rewriting existing args, handling DICT values:

```
url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/test/?question=false'
new_params = {'question': {'__X__':'__Y__'}}

add_url_params(url, new_params) == \
    'http://stackoverflow.com/test/?question=%7B%22__X__%22%3A+%22__Y__%22%7D'
```

### Talk is cheap. Show me the code.

Code itself. I've tried to describe it in details:

```
from json import dumps

try:
    from urllib import urlencode, unquote
    from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qsl, ParseResult
except ImportError:
    # Python 3 fallback
    from urllib.parse import (
        urlencode, unquote, urlparse, parse_qsl, ParseResult
    )


def add_url_params(url, params):
    """ Add GET params to provided URL being aware of existing.

    :param url: string of target URL
    :param params: dict containing requested params to be added
    :return: string with updated URL
    
    >> url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/test?answers=true'
    >> new_params = {'answers': False, 'data': ['some','values']}
    >> add_url_params(url, new_params)
    'https://stackoverflow.com/test?data=some&data=values&answers=false'
    """
    # Unquoting URL first so we don't lose existing args
    url = unquote(url)
    # Extracting url info
    parsed_url = urlparse(url)
    # Extracting URL arguments from parsed URL
    get_args = parsed_url.query
    # Converting URL arguments to dict
    parsed_get_args = dict(parse_qsl(get_args))
    # Merging URL arguments dict with new params
    parsed_get_args.update(params)

    # Bool and Dict values should be converted to json-friendly values
    # you may throw this part away if you don't like it :)
    parsed_get_args.update(
        {k: dumps(v) for k, v in parsed_get_args.items()
         if isinstance(v, (bool, dict))}
    )

    # Converting URL argument to proper query string
    encoded_get_args = urlencode(parsed_get_args, doseq=True)
    # Creating new parsed result object based on provided with new
    # URL arguments. Same thing happens inside urlparse.
    new_url = ParseResult(
        parsed_url.scheme, parsed_url.netloc, parsed_url.path,
        parsed_url.params, encoded_get_args, parsed_url.fragment
    ).geturl()

    return new_url
```

*Please be aware that there may be some issues, if you'll find one please let me know and we will make this thing better*

Comment: Perhaps add a try except with from urllib.parse to include Python 3 support? Thanks for the snippet, very useful!

Comment: Maybe add imports too ?

Comment: Unencodes encoded urls such as ``http://stackoverflow.com/with%2Fencoded?data=some&data=values&answe%2rs=false``.

Also, use three chevrons ```>>>``` to help doctests pick up your doctests

Comment: Why not change `parsed_get_args = dict(parse_qsl(get_args))` to `parsed_get_args = parse_qs(get_args)`

Answer (score 64):

You want to use URL encoding if the strings can have arbitrary data (for example, characters such as ampersands, slashes, etc. will need to be encoded).

Check out urllib.urlencode:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.urlencode({'lang':'en','tag':'python'})
'lang=en&tag=python'
```

In python3:

```
from urllib import parse
parse.urlencode({'lang':'en','tag':'python'})
```

Comment: In python 3, this has been moved to [urllib.parse.urlencode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode)

Answer (score 29):

You can also use the furl module https://github.com/gruns/furl

```
>>> from furl import furl
>>> print furl('http://example.com/search?q=question').add({'lang':'en','tag':'python'}).url
http://example.com/search?q=question&lang=en&tag=python
```

Comment: add would add duplicated params, not overwrite existing param

Answer (score 28):

If you are using the [requests lib](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/):

```
import requests
...
params = {'tag': 'python'}
requests.get(url, params=params)
```

Comment: @chefhose the question is ... relative to what ? You are not in a web page, there is no context to be relative to.

Answer (score 17):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9538343/1113207) answer, one-liner for simple cases (Python 3 code):

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlencode


url = "https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=question"
params = {'lang':'en','tag':'python'}

url += ('&' if urlparse(url).query else '?') + urlencode(params)
```

or:

```
url += ('&', '?')[urlparse(url).query == ''] + urlencode(params)
```

Comment: I know you mentioned "simple cases", but to clarify: it won't work properly if there is an `?` in the anchor (`#?stuff`).

Answer (score 16):

I find this more elegant than the two top answers:

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode, urlparse, parse_qs

def merge_url_query_params(url: str, additional_params: dict) -> str:
    url_components = urlparse(url)
    original_params = parse_qs(url_components.query)
    # Before Python 3.5 you could update original_params with 
    # additional_params, but here all the variables are immutable.
    merged_params = {**original_params, **additional_params}
    updated_query = urlencode(merged_params, doseq=True)
    # _replace() is how you can create a new NamedTuple with a changed field
    return url_components._replace(query=updated_query).geturl()

assert merge_url_query_params(
    'http://example.com/search?q=question',
    {'lang':'en','tag':'python'},
) == 'http://example.com/search?q=question&lang=en&tag=python'
```

The most important things I dislike in the top answers (they are nevertheless good):

- Łukasz: having to remember the index at which the `query` is in the URL components
- Sapphire64: the very verbose way of creating the updated `ParseResult`

What's bad about my response is the magically looking `dict` merge using unpacking, but I prefer that to updating an already existing dictionary because of my prejudice against mutability.

Comment: I was about to write an answer and found this. (y)

Answer (score 11):

Yes: use [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html).

From the [examples](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#examples) in the documentation:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> params = urllib.urlencode({'spam': 1, 'eggs': 2, 'bacon': 0})
>>> f = urllib.urlopen("http://www.musi-cal.com/cgi-bin/query?%s" % params)
>>> print f.geturl() # Prints the final URL with parameters.
>>> print f.read() # Prints the contents
```

Comment: Can you please give some brief example?

Comment: f.read() will show you the HTML page. To see the calling url, f.geturl()

Comment: -1 for using a HTTP request for parsing a URL (which is actually basic string manipulation). Plus the actual problem is not considered, because you need to know how the URL looks like to be able to append the query string correctly.

Comment: Either the author edited question either this answer is not related to it.

Comment: for python 3 this is now: `urllib.request.urlopen` and `urllib.parse.urlencode`

Answer (score 10):

`python3`, self explanatory I guess

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlencode, parse_qsl

url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search?keywords=engineer'

parsed = urlparse(url)
current_params = dict(parse_qsl(parsed.query))
new_params = {'location': 'United States'}
merged_params = urlencode({**current_params, **new_params})
parsed = parsed._replace(query=merged_params)

print(parsed.geturl())
# https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search?keywords=engineer&location=United+States
```

Comment: Watch out! This approach is using an internal function (indicated by the "_" before the function name) : `_replace`. It is not recommended to do so, because behavior of these internal functions may change or they may be removed without warning.

Comment: According to another stack overflow comment, admittedly from a few years ago, that's not true @GrazingScientist: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628852/changing-hostname-in-a-url#comment58437696_21629125

Comment: @yellow-saint: You are absolutly right, even with Python 3.9 `_replace` is still a valid public method. I did not know that. So, thanks for pointing this out. Still, this is not the usual case for methods starting with an underscore ("_").

Comment: Just to add, `_replace` is part of the publicly advertised API, as it's documented in the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse (```One such method is _replace(). The _replace() method will return a new ParseResult object replacing specified fields with new values```)

Answer (score 7):

I liked Łukasz version, but since urllib and urllparse functions are somewhat awkward to use in this case, I think it's more straightforward to do something like this:

```
params = urllib.urlencode(params)

if urlparse.urlparse(url)[4]:
    print url + '&' + params
else:
    print url + '?' + params
```

Comment: How about .query instead of [4] ?

Answer (score 5):

Use the various [`urlparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html) functions to tear apart the existing URL, [`urllib.urlencode()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) on the combined dictionary, then `urlparse.urlunparse()` to put it all back together again.

Or just take the result of `urllib.urlencode()` and concatenate it to the URL appropriately.

Answer (score 4):

Yet another answer:

```
def addGetParameters(url, newParams):
    (scheme, netloc, path, params, query, fragment) = urlparse.urlparse(url)
    queryList = urlparse.parse_qsl(query, keep_blank_values=True)
    for key in newParams:
        queryList.append((key, newParams[key]))
    return urlparse.urlunparse((scheme, netloc, path, params, urllib.urlencode(queryList), fragment))
```

Answer (score 2):

In python 2.5

```
import cgi
import urllib
import urlparse

def add_url_param(url, **params):
    n=3
    parts = list(urlparse.urlsplit(url))
    d = dict(cgi.parse_qsl(parts[n])) # use cgi.parse_qs for list values
    d.update(params)
    parts[n]=urllib.urlencode(d)
    return urlparse.urlunsplit(parts)

url = "http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=question"
add_url_param(url, lang='en') == "http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=question&lang=en"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I implemented it.

```
import urllib

params = urllib.urlencode({'lang':'en','tag':'python'})
url = ''
if request.GET:
   url = request.url + '&' + params
else:
   url = request.url + '?' + params
```

Worked like a charm. However, I would have liked a more cleaner way to implement this.

Another way of implementing the above is put it in a method.

```
import urllib

def add_url_param(request, **params):
   new_url = ''
   _params = dict(**params)
   _params = urllib.urlencode(_params)

   if _params:
      if request.GET:
         new_url = request.url + '&' + _params
      else:
         new_url = request.url + '?' + _params
   else:
      new_url = request.url

   return new_ur
```

Comment: urllib has been split up in Python 3.

The urllib.urlencode() function is now urllib.parse.urlencode(),