# How to add custom parameters to an URL query string with Python?

Tags: python

I need to add custom parameters to an URL query string using Python

Example:
This is the URL that the browser is fetching (GET):

```
/scr.cgi?q=1&ln=0
```

then some python commands are executed, and as a result I need to set following URL in the browser:

```
/scr.cgi?q=1&ln=0&SOMESTRING=1
```

Is there some standard approach?

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/2506379/2252728

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can use [`urlsplit()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlsplit) and [`urlunsplit()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlunsplit) to break apart and rebuild a URL, then use [`urlencode()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) on the parsed query string:

```
from urllib import urlencode
from urlparse import parse_qs, urlsplit, urlunsplit

def set_query_parameter(url, param_name, param_value):
    """Given a URL, set or replace a query parameter and return the
    modified URL.

    >>> set_query_parameter('http://example.com?foo=bar&biz=baz', 'foo', 'stuff')
    'http://example.com?foo=stuff&biz=baz'

    """
    scheme, netloc, path, query_string, fragment = urlsplit(url)
    query_params = parse_qs(query_string)

    query_params[param_name] = [param_value]
    new_query_string = urlencode(query_params, doseq=True)

    return urlunsplit((scheme, netloc, path, new_query_string, fragment))
```

Use it as follows:

```
>>> set_query_parameter("/scr.cgi?q=1&ln=0", "SOMESTRING", 1)
'/scr.cgi?q=1&ln=0&SOMESTRING=1'
```

Comment: Although this is several years old, I still feel the need to point this out since this question shows up on the front page of Google searches: If you care about order of parameters (which I assume you do, because of the `doseq=True` part), you should be using `parse_qsl()`, rather than `parse_qs()` -- the former returns a list of tuples, whereas the latter returns a dict, which is **not** guaranteed to preserve order when iterated over. Then, adding a param can be done via `query_params.append((param_name, param_value))`.

Answer (score 9):

Use [`urlsplit()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlsplit) to extract the query string, [`parse_qsl()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qsl) to parse it (or `parse_qs()` if you don't care about argument order), add the new argument, [`urlencode()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) to turn it back into a query string, [`urlunsplit()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlunsplit) to fuse it back into a single URL, then redirect the client.

Answer (score 2):

You can use python's url manipulation library **furl**.

```
import furl
f =  furl.furl("/scr.cgi?q=1&ln=0")  
f.args['SOMESTRING'] = 1
print(f.url)
```

Comment: It doesn't appear that furl is a built in module, so it would need to be installed first.

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib
url = "/scr.cgi?q=1&ln=0"
param = urllib.urlencode({'SOME&STRING':1})
url = url.endswith('&') and (url + param) or (url + '&' + param)
```

[the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html#examples)