# Python: Find URLs and add querystring pair

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to affilliateize some legacy text in a Django webapp. It's a pretty simple scope. The text has some amazon URLs in and I want to munge my `?tag=xxx` identifier onto the end of them.

I've written a template filter that I can quickly pass my text through but I'm slightly stuck on writing the regex logic.

```
t = text_from_template_engine
return re.sub(r'(https?://(?:www\.)?amazon\.co\.uk[\S]+)', r'\\\1?tag=xxx', t)
```

This seems to work on a very basic level but if the URL already has a querystring (as lots of organic Amazon URLs do by default), I would need an ampersand instead of a question mark.

There might be a quick way to detect two question marks and replace the second. I'm open to that suggestion.

What I'm really looking for is a regex-replace where I can pass the found string off to another method (in which I can detect existing question marks) that is expected to return the replacement string. Something like PHP's `preg_replace_callback` (et al). Does that exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the second parameter to `re.sub` can be a function, which takes a `match` object and returns a string. See [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub).

Comment: Mind... Blown... As usual, I need to RTFM ;)

Answer (score 0):

> There might be a quick way to detect two question marks and replace the second. I'm open to that suggestion.

this will get the 2 question marks.

```
(\?|(\?\?))
```

I believe the non-passive group number for the double question mark will  be $4 but you'll need to double check that and you can add back the single question mark in your replace.

Answer (score 0):

Once you find the URL, you're better off [parsing it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293460/how-to-add-custom-parameters-to-url-query-string-with-python-script/4293503#4293503) rather than hacking it into a regex.

Comment: Sure. But that's my problem. How do I find-and-replace in a way that lets me interfere in the middle?