# Treat regular expression between dashes

Tags: python, regex

Could you help me to use "sub" to change the numbers of these expressions:

> &AFL-03-123456
>
> &AFL-01-12345
>
> &AFL-02-123
>
> context: samsung-j7-duos-dual-chip-desbloqueado-oi-android-5.1-tela-5.5-16gb-wi-fi-4g-camera-13mp-branco&AFL-03-171644black

**In need to replace the numbers after the second dash for other numbers** (let's say 987654).

The number after the second dash, as you can see in the examples, may vary in  number of digits but they are always numbers.

The digits after de first dash are always 0X (X = 1,2 or 3).

The examples I gave are part of a bigger strings, so other "-" and "&" may appear anywhere else in the string, inclusively multiple times.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293460/how-to-add-custom-parameters-to-an-url-query-string-with-python

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you Wiktor, I have never seen anything like this, that's why I was trying to figure out a solution with regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(?<=&AFL-\d\d-)(\d+)` Will match the digits you want to replace, using a positive lookbehind, which ensures `&AFL-XX-` is there, but does not match them.

Combine this with [re.sub()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)

`re.sub(r"(?<=&AFL-\d\d-)(\d+)", string_to_fix, digits_you_want)`