# What is the syntax for adding a GET parameter to a URL?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, url, get

I am using [Python](https://www.python.org/) and [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/).

I need to get access to certain webpage by adding some elements to the url.

What is the syntax for adding a GET parameter to a URL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add params to given URL in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506379/add-params-to-given-url-in-python)

Answer (score 43):

You put `?` in the end of the url. After the `?` you put `var1=val1&var2=val2& ...`.

For example, if your raw url (without the get parameters) is http://www.example.com/ and you have two parameters, `param1=7` and `param2=seven`, then the full url should be:

http://www.example.com/?param1=7&param2=seven.

If you want to generate the `param1=7&param2=seven` in python, you can use a parameter dictionary, like this:

```
import urllib
parameters = urllib.urlencode({'param1':'7', 'param2':'seven'})
```

The value of `parameters` is `'param1=7&param2=seven'` so you can append the `parameters` string to a url like this:

```
raw_url = 'http://www.example.com/'
url = raw_url + '?' + params
```

Now the value of `url` is `'http://www.example.com/?param1=7&param2=seven'`.

Answer (score 7):

I am fairly certain this has been asked many times before, but the query parameters start with ? and are separated by & like so:

http://www.site.com/script.php?key=value&var=num

Answer (score 5):

http://www.foo.com/somepath?keyword1=value1&keyword2=value2&keyword3=value3

Comment: I know this is 5 years old, but this answer isn't entirely correct. If somepath refers to a file, such as somepath.php, then that is fine. But, if it refers to foo.com/somepath/index.php, then the parameters won't work (at least in PHP), it needs to be foo.com/somepath/?keyword1...

Answer (score 0):

The [`requests`](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) module handles this pretty cute:

```
>>> import requests
>>> reply = requests.get('https://example.com', {'abc':1, 'def':'<?>'})
>>> reply.url
'https://example.com/?abc=1&def=%3C%3F%3E'
```