# MultiValueDictKeyError - Passing GET parameter

Tags: python, html, django

I'm using django allauth.

All my users should have access to an url that is generated dynamically. Ex: www.example.com/uuid/

From this page they should be able to login with Soundcloud and should be redirected to this page after connecting.

I am using the following to get the previous link but I am receiving a good url in html but is empty on django.

```
#Html
<a href="/accounts/soundcloud/login?process=login?next={{request.path}}" name="next" value="next" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">Download</a>

#adapter.py
class AccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):

def get_login_redirect_url(self, request):
    #assert request.user.is_authenticated()
    #pass
    return request.GET['next']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your url - it should be:

```
href="/accounts/soundcloud/login?process=login&next={{request.path}}"
```

Notice the `&` instead of the second `?`.

Comment: Thanks! I was just noticing that and trying with /accounts/soundcloud/login/?next={{request.path}}, is there any difference?

Comment: @Juanvulcano that would not include the `process` url parameter but it would include the `next` parameter. See for instance [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5767509/2532070) for more detail.