# Python CGI - Creating a hyperlink with a query string

Tags: python, html, cgi

I was wondering how would I create a hyperlink to another page of my website with the query string being based off an item in a list returned from a database.

So for example:

```
for item in database
    generate hyperlink
```

the hyperlink would be something like test.py?message=24, where 24 is the item in the list returned from the database. The reason why it is in a for loop is because I have to put the hyperlinks in a table.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add params to given URL in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506379/add-params-to-given-url-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can look for `urlparse` module documentation which provides `urljoin` method to construct a absolute url by joining one base url with a relative path.