# Adding query parameters to a URL

Tags: python, python-2.7, url, web-scraping, urllib

I'm trying to automate data download from a website. I need to pass dynamic parameters to the site that changes daily. The html is structured in a table rather than forms. How do I pass my parameters and get a result from the url?

This is what I tried and it needs to be in python 2.7

```
import urllib

url = "https://disc.gsfc.nasa.gov/SSW/#keywords="

params = urllib.urlencode({'keyword':"(GPM_3IMERGHHE)", 't1':"2019-01-02", 't2':"2019-01-03", 'bboxBbox':"3.52,32.34,16.88,42.89"})
r = urllib.urlopen(url, params)

return = r.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the query parameters to the base url, so that `urllib.urlopen` creates a GET request.

```
>>> url = "https://disc.gsfc.nasa.gov/SSW/#keywords="

>>> params = {'keyword':"(GPM_3IMERGHHE)", 't1':"2019-01-02", 't2':"2019-01-03", 'bboxBbox':"3.52,32.34,16.88,42.89"}
>>> quoted_params = urllib.urlencode(params)
>>> quoted_params
'bboxBbox=3.52%2C32.34%2C16.88%2C42.89&t2=2019-01-03&keyword=%28GPM_3IMERGHHE%29&t1=2019-01-02'

>>> full_url = url + quoted_params
>>> full_url
'https://disc.gsfc.nasa.gov/SSW/#keywords=bboxBbox=3.52%2C32.34%2C16.88%2C42.89&t2=2019-01-03&keyword=%28GPM_3IMERGHHE%29&t1=2019-01-02'

>>> resp = urllib.urlopen(full_url)
>>> html = resp.read()
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I was able to make this work but have a different challenge now implementing it in IronPython 2.7.7. Please see my answer below and let me know if you can help. T

Answer (score 0):

I was able to Make this work in Python 2.7 as shown below but in I need to implement this in IronPython 2.7.7 because of a software dependency. I am getting an error saying "unknown url type: https" I understand versions of IronPython before 2.7.9 have issues with https. Is there a way to bypass the security check?

```
>>> import urllib
>>> url_keys = urllib.urlencode( {'action': "SUBSET", 'no_attr_prefix': 1, 'content_key_is_value': 1, 'force_array': 1,
...         'pretty': 0, 'start': "2019-01-02T00:00:00Z", 'end': "2019-01-04T23:59:59Z", 'south': 0.28,
...         'west': 32.77, 'north': 13.64, 'east': 44.72, 'variables': "precipitationCal", 'format': "netCDF",
...         'dataset_id': "GPM Level 3 IMERG Early Half Hourly 0.1 x 0.1 degree Precipitation V05", 'agent_id': "OPeNDAP"})
>>> url = "https://disc.gsfc.nasa.gov/daac-bin/SSW/SSW"
>>> r = urllib.urlopen(url, url_keys)
```