# How to change values of url query in python?

Tags: python, urlparse, url-parsing

```
 url = "http://www.example.com?type=a&type1=b&type2=c"
 urllist = get_urllist(url)
 trigger = ["'or '1'='1'"," 'OR '1'='2'","'OR a=a"]

def get_urllist(url): 
    url_parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
    #extract the query parameters of the URL 
    query =  urlparse.parse_qs(url_parsed.query)
    #get the list of query 
    query_list = query_list(query)
    #Get Base url 
    url = urlparse._replace(query=None).geturl()
    #modify url to get url_list 
    for query in query_list : 
       # change the original query to get the expected result 


 return url_list 


def query_list(query):
     for t in trigger:
         for key, value in query.items():
            query[key] += t
         query_list.append(query) 

     return query_list
```

How to return a list of URLs by changing the query parameter values?

Original url = "http://www.example.com?type=a&type1=b&type2=c"

Expected Result:

Url_list=  ["http://www.example.com?type=a'OR '1'='1'&type1=b'OR '1'='1'&type2=c'OR '1'='1'","http://www.example.com?type=a'OR '1'='2'&type1=b'OR '1'='2'&type2=c'OR '1'='2'","http://www.example.com?type=a'OR a=a&type1=b'OR a=a&type2=c''OR a=a" ]

Comment: Does the `OR xxx` make sense to you?

Comment: Meanwhile is your `trigger` correct? a list whit a length 1？

Comment: ' OR '1'='1'  is used to check for SQL injection. I am just trying to automate it .  Changed trigger .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**In Python2.x**

You can use [`urlparse.urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlparse) function and `ParseResult._replace` method:

```
import urlparse
url = "http://www.example.com?type=a&type1=b&type2=c"
trigger = ["'or '1'='1'"," 'OR '1'='2'","'OR a=a"]

parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
querys = parsed.query.split("&")
result = []
for pairs in trigger:
    new_query = "&".join([ "{}{}".format(query, pairs) for query in querys])
    parsed = parsed._replace(query=new_query)
    result.append(urlparse.urlunparse(parsed))
```

**Note**

The [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#module-urlparse) module is renamed to `urllib.parse` in **`Python 3`**. The [`2to3`](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-2to3) tool will automatically adapt imports when converting your sources to Python 3.

**In Python3.x**

You can use [`urlparse.urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#url-parsing) function as well.

```
import urllib.parse as urlparse
url = "http://www.example.com?type=a&type1=b&type2=c"
trigger = ["'or '1'='1'"," 'OR '1'='2'","'OR a=a"]

parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
querys = parsed.query.split("&")
result = []
for pairs in trigger:
    new_query = "&".join([ "{}{}".format(query, pairs) for query in querys])
    parsed = parsed._replace(query=new_query)
    result.append(urlparse.urlunparse(parsed))
```

DEMO OUTPUT:

```
["http://www.example.com?type=a'or '1'='1'&type1=b'or '1'='1'&type2=c'or '1'='1'", "http://www.example.com?type=a 'OR '1'='2'&type1=b 'OR '1'='2'&type2=c 'OR '1'='2'", "http://www.example.com?type=a'OR a=a&type1=b'OR a=a&type2=c'OR a=a"]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this method is deprecated at least on python 3.  You'll get: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urlparse'

Comment: The problem with this method is that you are using the "private" method `_replace`

Comment: Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628852/changing-hostname-in-a-url

Comment: @AlexandreS `_replace` came from here https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._replace

Answer (score 9):

You can use the package [furl](https://github.com/gruns/furl).

```py
from furl import furl

url = furl("http://www.example.com?type=a&type1=b&type2=c")
url.set({"type": "a'or '1'='1'"})
url.url
```

gives the output: `http://www.example.com?type=a%27or+%271%27%3D%271%27`

and decoded: `http://www.example.com?type=a'or '1'='1'`

Answer (score 6):

### Here is a simple example:

```py
def patch_url(url, **kwargs):
    from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlencode, parse_qsl
    return urlparse(url)._replace(query=urlencode(
        dict(parse_qsl(urlparse(url).query), **kwargs))).geturl()


assert patch_url("https://httpbin.org/get?hello=world", hello="human") \
       == "https://httpbin.org/get?hello=human"
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid using the private method `_replace()` I just made a new `SplitResult`, replacing the old params where necessary.

```py
p = parse.urlsplit(url)
url = parse.SplitResult("https", *p[1:]).geturl()
```

I'm using `urlsplit()` which returns `SplitResult`, but I would imagine you can do the same thing with `ParseResult` returned from `urlparse()`. Both are named tuples. Everthing is described in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html)

For the query specifically, also do `parse_qs()` to get a dict of params and `urlencode()` to get back a query string.

```py
>>> parse.urlencode({"a":1, "b":"yes", "c":[1,2,3]}, doseq=False)
'a=1&b=yes&c=%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%5D'
>>> parse.urlencode({"a":1, "b":"yes", "c":[1,2,3]}, doseq=True)
'a=1&b=yes&c=1&c=2&c=3'
```