# Redact and remove password from URL

Tags: python, url-parsing

I have an URL like this:

```
https://user:password@example.com/path?key=value#hash
```

The result should be:

```
https://user:???@example.com/path?key=value#hash
```

I could use a regex, but instead I would like to parse the URL a high level data structure, then operate on this data structure, then serializing to a string.

Is this possible with Python?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the built in `urlparse` to query out the password from a url. It is available in both Python 2 and 3, but under different locations.

[Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) `import urlparse`

[Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) `from urllib.parse import urlparse`

**Example**

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

parsed = urlparse("https://user:password@example.com/path?key=value#hash")
parsed.password # 'password'

replaced = parsed._replace(netloc="{}:{}@{}".format(parsed.username, "???", parsed.hostname))
replaced.geturl() # 'https://user:???@example.com/path?key=value#hash'
```

See also this question: [Changing hostname in a url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628852/changing-hostname-in-a-url)

Comment: Not a very good answer, this will return something like `https://None:???@example.com/` if there was no username and password in the first place.

Comment: @Patrick please feel free to leave your own answer, or submit an edit request for this answer, if you think some more information should be provided.

Comment: @Patrick like most answers here, this shows how to do the thing that was asked.  It can be worked into comprehensive code by the reader.  A trivial if statement can check to see if `parsed.password` and `parsed.username` exists and adjust behaviour accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

def redact_url(url: str) -> str:
    url_components = urlparse(url)
    if url_components.username or url_components.password:
        url_components = url_components._replace(
            netloc=f"{url_components.username}:???@{url_components.hostname}",
        )

    return url_components.geturl()
```

Answer (score 1):

The `pip` module already have an internal utility function which does exactly this.

```
>>> from pip._internal.utils.misc import redact_auth_from_url
>>> 
>>> redact_auth_from_url("https://user:password@example.com/path?key=value#hash")
'https://user:****@example.com/path?key=value#hash'
>>> redact_auth_from_url.__doc__
'Replace the password in a given url with ****.'
```

This will provide the expected result even if the url does not contain username or password.

```
>>> redact_auth_from_url("https://example.com/path?key=value#hash") 
'https://example.com/path?key=value#hash'
```