# How to redact password from URL in Rust?

Tags: url, rust, url-parsing

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46905367/6699447) but specific to [rust](/questions/tagged/rust). How can I readact password from a URL?. This is mainly for logging purposes.

To make it clear I am looking for [similar kind of API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74600180/6699447) in [rust](/questions/tagged/rust).

```
>>> from pip._internal.utils.misc import redact_auth_from_url
>>> 
>>> redact_auth_from_url("https://user:password@example.com/path?key=value#hash")
'https://user:****@example.com/path?key=value#hash'
>>> redact_auth_from_url.__doc__
'Replace the password in a given url with ****.'
```

I did check the [rust-url](https://github.com/servo/rust-url) crate but I could not find an equivalent function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`set_password`](https://docs.rs/url/latest/url/struct.Url.html#method.set_password) in conjunction with [`password`](https://docs.rs/url/latest/url/struct.Url.html#method.password):

```rust
if url.password().is_some() {
    url.set_password(Some("****"));
}
```

Or, as a function mimicking the `redact_auth_from_url` interface:

```rust
fn redact_auth_from_url(url: &Url) -> Cow<'_, Url> {
    if url.password().is_some() {
        let mut owned_url = url.clone();
        if owned_url.set_password(Some("****")).is_ok() {
            Cow::Owned(owned_url)
        } else {
            Cow::Borrowed(url)
        }
    } else {
        Cow::Borrowed(url)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. `set_password` is the API I was looking for. I could also find similar open issue in `rust-url` repository([Redact password in logs](https://github.com/servo/rust-url/issues/714)). So may be we can expect more direct API in future.