# strip username and password from url with basic auth

Tags: python

I am trying to take the username and password from a url and put it back together to use it again in its complete form but without the basic auth part.

I am trying something like the below but the result is not what I expect.

```
from urllib.parse import urlsplit, urlunsplit
parts = urlsplit("http://user:pwd@host:8080/path?query=foo", allow_fragments=True)
auth = (parts.username, parts.password)
print(urlunsplit((parts.scheme, parts.hostname, str(parts.port), parts.path, parts.query)))
# http://host/8080?/path#query=foo
```

It would be even better if I could set username and password to None on the parts and just call `geturl` but I get errors that I can't change attributes.

```py
from urllib.parse import urlsplit
parts = urlsplit("http://user:pwd@host:8080/path?query=foo", allow_fragments=True)
auth = (parts.username, parts.password)
parts.password = None
parts.username = None
print(parts.geturl())
# AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Note, that I want to preserve the username and password in a separate tuple.

Comment: According to the documentation [**`urlsplit`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlsplit) returns a `namedtuple`. You can [replace fields](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._replace) in the tuple by saying `part._replace(password=None, username=None)`, which returns a new `namedtuple` (as `part` is immutable).

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21629125

Comment: Have you contemplated using `re`. Example:`tuple(re.search("\/.*?\@", my_url).group(0)[2:-1].split(":"))`

Comment: I have tried that already peter it said unknown argument. I was thinking for a minute to include this but since its an *private* method I dont think we should actually use it anyway. `ValueError: Got unexpected field names: ['password', 'username']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`urlunsplit` requires a tuple that looks like the same thing that `urlsplit` returned. The second element in that tuple is the `netloc` - which looks like:
`user:pwd@host:port`

So you need to pass something similar to it. You can do that by modifying the `parts.netloc` that you get from `urlsplit` & passing it to `urlunsplit`:

```
from urllib.parse import urlsplit, urlunsplit

parts = urlsplit("http://user:pwd@host:8080/path?query=foo", allow_fragments=True)
auth = (parts.username, parts.password)

netloc = parts.netloc.split('@')[1]  # ignore the auth part. You should check the length after the split obviously
reconstruction_parts = (parts.scheme, netloc, parts.path, parts.query, parts.fragment)

print(urlunsplit(reconstruction_parts))
```

Result:

```
http://host:8080/path?query=foo
```