# How to encode whitespaces as '+' in the url using urllib3?

Tags: python, url-encoding, urllib3

I'm using urllib3 on Python 2.7. I need to send a request to a website that gives the desired response only when the spaces are separated by '+' and **not** by '%2b'.

```
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
var = 'foo bar'
url = 'https://foo.com/release?q=' + var
webdata = http.request('GET', url)
```

How can I do this in urllib3?

Comment: Use `urlencode` for this aims http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506379/add-params-to-given-url-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import urllib
print(urllib.quote_plus('Hello world'))
```

> > > > Hello+world

Comment: I was hoping to do it within urllib3 alone, which seem to encode it only the '%20' way. But this works as well, thanks!

Comment: You can't, unless you replace spaces im your string with plus signs. I would rather recommend you to use requests instead of any urllib package for simpler and a much more complete handset of functions.