# How to format string in url by python?

Tags: python, string, url, format

I can format the link (link1)  with 1 variable however when I want to format the link (link2) with 2 variables, it throws an error ( ValueError: unsupported format character 'A' (0x41) at index 94)
The link2 is supposed to be :  https://widget.s24.com/applications/1e082c83/widgets/422/products?searchTerm=Topper&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.real.de%2Fproduct%2F324093002%2F

is there any solution for this ?

```
i = 324093002
b = "Topper"
link_product = 'https://www.real.de/product/%s/'
link_keyword = 'https://widget.s24.com/applications/1e082c83/widgets/422/products?searchTerm=*%s*&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.real.de%2Fproduct%2F*%s*%2F'
link1 = link_product %i
link2 = link_keyword % (i, b)
```

Comment: `%s` expects string but `324093002` is number - did you try `str(i)` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add params to given URL in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506379/add-params-to-given-url-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the format() method:

```
i = 324093002
b = "Topper"
link_product = 'https://www.real.de/product/{}/'
link_keyword = 'https://widget.s24.com/applications/1e082c83/widgets/422/products?searchTerm={}&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.real.de%2Fproduct%2F{}%2F'

link1 = link_product.format(i)
link2 = link_keyword.format(b, i)
print(link2)


'https://widget.s24.com/applications/1e082c83/widgets/422/products?searchTerm=Topper&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.real.de%2Fproduct%2F324093002%2F'
```

Comment: your `i` and `b` are backward in the `format()`

Comment: Also drop the `*` around the `{}` to match the desired string. might as well change the first URL too.

Answer (score 2):

Char `%` has special meaning in string formatting - like `%s`, `%i`, etc.- and you have `%3A` `%2F` which are not correct formatting. You have to use `%%` to inform Python that you need normal char `%` -  `%%3A` `%%2F`

```
i = 324093002
b = "Topper"
link_keyword = 'https://widget.s24.com/applications/1e082c83/widgets/422/products?searchTerm=*%s*&origin=https%%3A%%2F%%2Fwww.real.de%%2Fproduct%%2F*%s*%%2F'

link2 = link_keyword % (i, b)
print(link2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use f-string formatting (> Python 3.6). See [here](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) for more info.

```
i = 324093002
b = "Topper"
link_product = f"https://www.real.de/product/{i}/"
link_keyword = f"https://widget.s24.com/applications/1e082c83/widgets/422/products?searchTerm=*{i}*&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.real.de%2Fproduct%2F*{b}*%2F"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make use of `urllib`, to prevent mixing data with an already urlencoded URL:

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode, urljoin, urlparse

i = 324093002
b = "Topper"
link_product = urljoin('https://www.real.de/product/', str(i))

link_url = 'https://widget.s24.com/applications/1e082c83/widgets/422/products?{}'
link_params = {'searchTerm': i, 'origin': link_product}

link_keyword = link_url.format(urlencode(link_params))
print(link_keyword)
```

Out:

```
https://widget.s24.com/applications/1e082c83/widgets/422/products?searchTerm=324093002&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.real.de%2Fproduct%2F324093002
```

Note:
Especially when `b` changes into a term that uses non URL safe characters, like `Top top` or `iPhone7+` things get messed up using regular string formatting.