# How can I called a view within another view django

Tags: django, django-views

Currently, I have a view that essentially closes a lead, meaning that it simply copies the information from one table (leads) to another (deals), now what I really would like to do is that after clicking close, the user is redirected to another page where the user can update some entries (sales forecast), I have a view that updates the lead, so I thought that I can do something like below:

```
@login_required
def close_lead(request):
    id = request.GET.get('project_id', '')
    keys = Leads.objects.select_related().get(project_id=id)
    form_dict = {'project_id': keys.project_id,
                 'agent': keys.agent,
                 'client': keys.point_of_contact,
                 'company': keys.company,
                 'service': keys.services,
                 'licenses': keys.expected_licenses,
                 'country_d': keys.country
                 }

    deal_form = NewDealForm(request.POST or None,initial=form_dict)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if deal_form.is_valid():
            deal_form.save()
            obj = Leads.objects.get(project_id=id)
            obj.status = "Closed"
            obj.save(update_fields=['status'])
            ## Changing the Forecast Table Entry
            forecast = LeadEntry.objects.filter(lead_id=id)
            for i in forecast:
                m = i
                m.stage = "Deal"
                m.save(update_fields=['stage'])
            messages.success(request, 'You have successfully updated the status from open to Close')
            update_forecast(request,id)

        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Error updating your Form')


    return render(request,
                  "account/close_lead.html",
                  {'form': deal_form})
```

This view provides the formset that I want to update after closing the lead

```
@login_required
def update_forecast(request,lead_id):
    # Gets the lead queryset
    lead = get_object_or_404(Leads,pk=lead_id)
    #Create an inline formset using Leads the parent model and LeadEntry the child model
    FormSet = inlineformset_factory(Leads,LeadEntry,form=LeadUpdateForm,extra=0)
    if request.method == "POST":
        formset = FormSet(request.POST,instance=lead)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return redirect('forecast_lead_update',lead_id=lead.project_id)

    else:
        formset = FormSet(instance=lead)

    context = {
                'formset':formset
               }
    return render(request,"account/leadentry_update.html",context)
```

As you can see I’m calling this function update_forecast(request,id) after validating the data in the form, and I would have expected to be somehow redirected to the HTML page specified on that function, however, after clicking submit, the form from the first view is validated but then nothing happens, so I'm the function doesn't render the HTML page

My question how can I leverage existing functions in my views?, obviously, I will imagine that following the DRY principles you can do that in Django, so what am I doing wrong ?, how can I call an existing function within another function in views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view returns a response object. In your current code, you're calling a second view but not doing anything with its response. If you just wanted to display static content (not a form that might lead to an action that cares about the current URL) you could return the response object from the second view - `return update_forecast(request, id)`.

But since your second view is displaying a form, you care about what the action for the view from the second form is. The typical Django idiom is to have forms submit to the current page's URL - that wouldn't work if you just call it and return its response object. You *could* customize the action in the second view, say adding an optional parameter to the view, but the usual idiom for form processing is to redirect to the view you want to show on success. Just as you do in the `update_forecast` view. Something like this:

```
messages.success(request, 'You have successfully updated the status from open to Close')
return redirect('update_forecast', lead_id=id)
```

Comment: Thanks, I did that but getting an error - django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'update_forecast' not found. 'update_forecast' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: Sorry, obviously, you didn't know the name of the URL, so after changing that it works --- If I will add a third parameter to the function redirect('update_forecast', lead_id=id, place), where the place is an indicator on which view is it coming from , would that work?

Comment: Not automatically - the arguments will be used to try to resolve the view name to a URL, see the docs for details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect. It'd work if you make `place` part of the URL pattern for that view, possibly an optional one. Or use `reverse` to get the base URL and then add a query parameter before passing it to `redirect`, though that requires a little care to do correctly in terms of constructing the target URL.

Comment: You'd want `place` as a kwarg rather than a base arg if you do make it part of the URL pattern, `lead_id=id, place=place`. But I'd probably set it as a query param myself, for instance this is similar to what the login system does to send you back to the originally requested page after login. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49957974/2337736 shows a good way to add params to an arbitrary URL without risking getting the encoding wrong, using the common but not standard-library `requests` package.